# Function works in code but not as a UDF in Sheet

Tags: string, macos, vba, find, udf

I coded a function that searches column A:A for a string (passed as an input) and returns the full content of the first cell in range A:A that contains that piece of string...

The function works fine when I call it from the `Sub test()`, but I can't make it work in the sheet directly... ie by writing `=Find_First("lala")`. It just returns "not found" although the piece of text is indeed in A:A

Here's my code.. Thanks for your help!!

```
Public Function Find_First(FindString As String) As String

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim TrimString As String

     Application.Volatile True

    TrimString = Trim(FindString)

    If TrimString <> "" Then
        With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=TrimString, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)

            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Find_First = Rng.Value
                MsgBox ("Found at: " & Rng.Address)
            Else
                Find_First = "not found"
                MsgBox ("Not found ")
            End If
        End With
    End If

End Function

Sub test()
    MsgBox Find_First(" lala   ")
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code being called as worksheet function works fine for me.

Comment: Hello, that's strange... Could it be related to the fact that I am using excel for mac 2014 version 14?

Comment: Is any kind of setting that may be wrong? What direction should I look at? I cant find anything helpful online... Thanks !

Comment: Since you are on mac I think you may edit your question and add "osx" tag or another appropriate to attract experts.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved... :)
The issue is that the find method is not working properly on office excel 2011 for MAC.
See this link for the workaround, posted by Rick Rothstein:
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/878953-excel-visual-basic-applications-function-works-code-but-not-udf-spreadsheet.html